# Fastest way to load images into a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

i have a UIScrollView which holds different UIView container. Each container has to load six UIImages. When scrolling i need to adjust the contents within the "layoutSubviews" method. 
Unfortunately loading these images affects in hiccups when the new container and the images will be created.

I´m loading the images async via "dispatch_async". I also used small 32x32px thumbnails which will be replaced with the full image 256x256px image. Unfortunately its stuttering..

Here´s the code of the "initWithFrame" method of such a UIView.
These UIViews will later be added as a subview to the UIView container.

```
// load ThumbnailImage and replace it later with the fullImage
        NSString* thumbImageName =  [self.data.imageName stringByAppendingString:@"_small"];

 NSString* fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: thumbImageName  ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation]];
[self setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{      

NSString* fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: self.data.imageName  ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation]];
                [self setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            });
        });
```

Is this the faster way to load images into a UIView?
How does Apple implemented the really fluid image view inside the "Photo.app" when scrolling between different fullscreen images?

I don´t know if it would make sense to use CoreImage?
Any advice would be great!

Thanks for any help and your time.
Have a nice day.

Comment: The fastest way would be to keep cached images in memory (maybe thumbnails and load full-size images in background).

Comment: Ok, cool Thanks. But there is no other, faster way to improve the time the iPad loads from the local disk, right? just the known UIImage methods like "imageNamed" and all the "imageWith***"... ?

Comment: I don't have any practice, so I can't recommend something exact. You may take a look for png-files optimization, for example here: http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Something i was looking for!